# handling UIResponderStandardEditActions in UIwebview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I want to handle copy/select/selectAll/Patse options of  `UIResponderStandardEditActions` in webview. but i am facing problem, the copy action never called and also i observed that , in function((I have webview where i am displaying text using `TTStyledTextLabel`)..

```
canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
```

The copy: action never comes..but i do see that all other options like select , selectAll and cut actions getting called, even though the copy action never called in above function when i select text in webview the copy action is enabled but action never gets called..

Comment: You can start with the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29335786/2066428) to change `canPerformAction:withSender:` implementation and extend it to all `UIResponderStandardEditActions`

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your problem yet? If you did please post your solution. I'm having the same problem with the paste function.

The solution I found, and I know it's not ideal, its to detect the events through javascript.

I use javascript to detect when a paste happens, call my objectiveC function to work with the data, and call a JS function from the objectiveC to paste the content on the webview.